# Connect 2 users when they come in certian region in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, ibeacon, geofencing

I am working on one application where two users uses the application and am creating the region based on the user's current location.

Now what I want to achieve is when they come close and their region interact with each other, then both get notified that they have into one region.

Like showing in the picture. In picture1 the yellow is the region of one user,

[image]

as soon as their region interact with each other like depict in the second picture then both got notified.

[image]

How I can achieve that?

Comment: 1. When you say 'regoin' do you mean a logical area or are you using iBeacon, because, in iOS world the 'region has a specific meaning. 2. What do you mean the users are 'connected'? Do you plan to use bluetooth or XMPP etc? Your question is too generic. You need to explain what you have tried so far, adn where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: 1. I am planning to use iBeacon. 2. What I mean connected, when their region interact with each other like depict in the second picture the both got notified. I want to know, what approach should I follow to achieve this.

Comment: Update the question with these specifics. and also, as i mentioned earlier, you need to explain what you have tried so far, and where exactly you are stuck specifically

Comment: You can do this firebase.
In firebase GeoFire will help you. Suppose you need all user that will come in 10KM radios. In GeoFire you can do easily.
When any user enter in this region and exit form your region GeoFire will notify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to accomplish this with iBeacon/CoreLocation/CoreBluetooth is with an app that transmits an iBeacon advertisement and looks for iBeacon advertisements:

- All apps would use the same ProximityUUID for transmitting and receiving.
- Apps would transit a unique major/minor combination identifying the app install.
- Apps would monitor and range for beacons matching this ProximityUUID.
- Apps would transmit an iBeacon advertisement with it's unique id encoded in major/minor.
- When a beacon is ranged, the major/minor is read identifying the other user nearby.

A few limitations of this approach:

- iOS can only transit in the foreground
- Ranging is limited to 10 secs in the background by default (extendable to 180 secs) after first beacon detection or leaving the foreground
- If one beacon remains in the vicinity, a second beacon appearing will not trigger a background wakeup to start ranging

Answer (score 0):

With CoreLocation, you likely are looking for the:

```
didEnterRegion
```

and

```
didExitRegion
```

methods. You can use these to alert users on either event. For example as below (sample I've borrowed and modded in my own app):

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var manager = CLLocationManager?()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    manager = CLLocationManager()
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = //
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = //
    let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let radius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(//)
    let identifier: String = "YOUR UNIQUE ID"

    let activeRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)

    manager?.distanceFilter = //
    manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    activeRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    activeRegion.notifyOnExit = true

    manager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()


    manager?.delegate = self
    manager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

    manager?.startMonitoringForRegion(activeRegion)
    manager?.startUpdatingLocation()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("These are the regions I'm monitoring: \(manager.monitoredRegions)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("These are the locations: \(location.latitude) \(location.longitude)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)  {
    NSLog("Entered")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    NSLog("Exited")
}
```

}